# Prompt: replace custom path with a short word like ~ for home

Tags: zsh, prompt, oh-my-zsh

When I call `cd /Users/mu3/apps` the prompt simplifies it like this:

```
mu3 [~/apps]:
```

Is this possible to do the same for custom path like `cd /Users/mu3/Development/Web/test`:

```
mu3 [DEV/test]:
```

I'm using iTerm + oh-my-zsh.

---

UPD: I wasn't specific enough and also discovered some new information.
Since I use [`agnoster`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes#agnoster) theme for [`zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) shell, it handles a prompt look by itself.

So I ended up with changing [this line](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/8d6fccef81793001cb230ef9c4ff0b77b45682f0/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme#L167):

```
prompt_segment blue black '%~'
```

to this:

```
PWDshort="${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
PWDshort="${PWDshort/\~\/_cld\/Dropbox\/Dev\/Web/DEV}"
prompt_segment blue black $PWDshort
```

[image]

Now the problem is that any update apparently breaks this.
Is there any better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: I don't know `zsh` (I use `bash`), but is there some equivalent in `zsh` to just saying `PS1='\u [\W]: '` instead of `PS1='\u [\w]: '`?  The uppercase W should do the trick (show basename only of current directory).

Comment: The nature of the breakage is not clear from the description.

Comment: @ThomasDickey «this line» link points to github repository that can be updated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard way to define directory abbreviations for the prompt is to use [named directories](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Static-named-directories). Named directories are used when expanding the [`%~`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Shell-state) prompt escape sequence, generalizing `~` to abbreviate your home directory and `~bob` to abbreviate Bob's home directory.

```
mu3 [~]: cd /Users/mu3/Development/Web/test
mu3 [~/Development/Web/test]: hash -d test=$PWD
mu3 [~test]: cd config
mu3 [~test/config]:
```

The usual way to do this would be to put `hash -d test=~/Development/Web/test` in your `.zshrc`. In addition to being used to abbreviate prompts, the named directory can also be used to abbreviate paths, e.g. you can run `cd ~test` to switch to that directory.

With this method, the abbreviated form always starts with a `~`.

Comment: How would that interact with an attempt to cd to the home directory of a user named 'test'?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Named directories take precedence: zsh will effectively forget that there's a user named `test` with a home directory.

Comment: @mu3 Sorry, it seems that you're running into some oh-my-zsh weirdness, and the only advice I have in that case is to not use oh-my-zsh, which is pretty-looking but also pretty useless.

Comment: you're right about zsh and `~Dev` definitely is much clearer and wo/ workarounds

Answer (score 2):

You can (as in `bash`) use a function in your prompt.  Here is an example:

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST

print_dir(){
  case $PWD in
  (*/Development*)
    echo DEV/${PWD:t}
    ;;
  (*)
    echo $PWD
    ;;
  esac
}

export PROMPT=$'[$(print_dir)]: '
```

The [`zshall`](http://gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=zshall) manual page documents `PROMPT_SUBST`:

> If the `PROMPT_SUBST` option is set, the prompt string is first subjected to *parameter expansion*, *command substitution* and *arithmetic expansion*. See [zshexpn(1)](http://gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=zshexpn).